# Fill missing array values using extrapolated plot Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib

I have a 2D numpy array containing `X` and `Y` data. The axis `X` contain time information with resolution of nano seconds. My problem occours because I need to compare `simulated signal` and a `real signal`. The problem of the `simulated signal` is that the simulator, with optimization purposes, has a diferent step sizes, as show on fig. 1.

[image: Fig 1 - Simulated Data]

In other hand my real data was acquired by an osciloscope and your data has  exaclty 1 ns of diference between each point recorded. Because of this I need to have the same scale in the `X` axis to make a correct comparasion. How can I get the extra points to make my data with a constant step between the points?

**EDIT 1**

I need that this new points fill my array to make the simulated data with constant step, like show in fig 2.
[image: Fig 2]

The green points show an example of data extracted from extrapolated data.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You may show the code you have and the undesired outcome of it such that one can help you improving it.

Comment: Not totally clear on what you want but it sounds like `SciPy` interpolation may help (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html)

Comment: Please note that while images are often useful, in this case they do not convey the necessary information. Do you want to interpolate the given curve? Do you want to show two different curves on the same scale? Break the problem down to a simple case of 5 numbers or so and provide those numbers in the question. Then clearly state what you'd expect for those numbers to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was solved using `scipy interpolate` module. Eg.

**interpolate.py**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate as inter
import numpy as np


Fs = 0.1
f = 0.01
sample = 10

x = np.arange(sample)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)

inte = inter.interp1d(x,y)

new_x = np.arange(0,9,0.1)
new_y = inte(new_x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(new_x,new_y,s=5,marker='.')
ax1.scatter(x,y,s=50,marker='*')

plt.show()
```

This code give the following result.

[image]

---

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to simply duplicate some points (adding a point with same average value doesn't modify much most of statistical values)
So you have to change the dataset everytime you change the scale. Takes lots of time every scale change but it is super easy. If you don't have to change the scale too much, you can try.